# Get cient "closed" dialogs

Tags: telethon

The account has been added to a private conversation(not groups) by phone number.How do I get this dialog data?

It is not included in the list of the general method of obtaining [dialogs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html?highlight=iter_dialogs#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.get_dialogs) (dialogs (open conversations/subscribed channels)).

Does such a possibility even exist? For example, when I don't have the appropriate dialog identifiers or its name. But it exist in account's conversations.